# Check if Excel workbook is open from another Office 2010 App

Tags: excel, file, vba, outlook

This continues from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208805/object-trouble-accessing-excel-from-outlook). I tried the suggested fix to check if an Excel file is open locally from an Outlook macro (Office 2010).

```
Public Sub UpdateFileIndex(ByVal FullFilePath As String, ByVal DocNo As String)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.WorkSheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(FullFilePath).Application
    Debug.Print "Error = " & Err

    If Err.Number = 0 Then ' Workbook is open locally
        ' Do stuff
    ElseIf Err.Number = 429 Then ' Workbook is not open locally
        ' Do different stuff
    End If

    ' Do a bunch of other stuff
End Sub
```

Now for open or closed files given by `FullFilePath` (e.g. `"C:\Data\Data.xlsx"`):

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(FullFilePath).Application`

gives me 0 error either way. (i.e. it opens the file if it's not open.)

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(Dir(FullFilePath)).Application`

gives me -214722120 for both cases. (Automation error)

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`

gives me 0 when open and 429 when not open. See below.

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(Dir(FullFilePath), "Excel.Application")`

gives me 432 for both cases. (File name or class name not found during Automation operation)

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(FullFilePath, "Excel.Application")`

gives me 432 for both cases.

So the only case that works is the initially suggested fix (see link at top), which cannot find the file unless it's in the first instance of Excel open locally, which may not always be the case (i.e. it may be open in a second instance).

Ultimately I'd like to check if the file is open on the network, and if it is check if it's open locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple Excel instances open then this is what I suggest.

**Logic**

1. Check if your workbook is open or not. If not open, then open it.
2. If it is open then it could be in any Excel instance.
3. Find the Excel instance and bind with the relevant workbook.

`GetObject` unfortunately will return the same instance every time unless you close that Excel instance. Also there is no reliable way to get it to loop through all Excel instances. Talking of reliability, I would turn your attention towards APIs. The 3 APIs that we will use is `FindWindowEx` , `GetDesktopWindow` and `AccessibleObjectFromWindow&`

See this example (**TRIED AND TESTED in EXCEL 2010**)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow& Lib "oleacc" _
(ByVal hwnd&, ByVal dwId&, riid As GUID, xlWB As Object)

Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM = &HFFFFFFF0

Private Type GUID
    lData1 As Long
    iData2 As Integer
    iData3 As Integer
    aBData4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim oXLApp As Object, wb As Object
    Dim sPath As String, sFileName As String, SFile As String, filewithoutExt As String
    Dim IDispatch As GUID

    sPath = "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\"
    sFileName = "Data.xlsx": filewithoutExt = "Data"
    SFile = sPath & sFileName

    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(SFile)

    '~~> If file is open
    If Ret = True Then
        Dim dsktpHwnd As Long, hwnd As Long, mWnd As Long, cWnd As Long

        SetIDispatch IDispatch

        dsktpHwnd = GetDesktopWindow

        hwnd = FindWindowEx(dsktpHwnd, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)

        mWnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)

        While mWnd <> 0 And cWnd = 0
            cWnd = FindWindowEx(mWnd, 0&, "EXCEL7", filewithoutExt)
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(dsktpHwnd, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
            mWnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
        Wend

        '~~> We got the handle of the Excel instance which has the file
        If cWnd > 0 Then
            '~~> Bind with the Instance
            Call AccessibleObjectFromWindow(cWnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IDispatch, wb)
            '~~> Work with the file
            With wb.Application.Workbooks(sFileName)
                '
                '~~> Rest of the code
                '
            End With
        End If

    '~~> If file is not open
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

        '~~> If not found then create new instance
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(SFile)
        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SetIDispatch(ByRef ID As GUID)
    With ID
        .lData1 = &H20400
        .iData2 = &H0
        .iData3 = &H0
        .aBData4(0) = &HC0
        .aBData4(1) = &H0
        .aBData4(2) = &H0
        .aBData4(3) = &H0
        .aBData4(4) = &H0
        .aBData4(5) = &H0
        .aBData4(6) = &H0
        .aBData4(7) = &H46
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file is open
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: This worked perfectly once I'd changed `cWnd = FindWindowEx(mWnd, 0&, "EXCEL7", filewithoutExt)` to use sFileName as the last parameter. Thanks again.

Comment: One last thing though... After `Call AccessibleObjectFromWindow(cWnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IDispatch, wb)` I would link to a worksheet object depending on the value of DocNo (using `Set xlSheet = ...`). I'm not sure how to do this from within the `With` construct. Is there a way to do this, or link directly to the workbook object (like with `Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks("File Index.xlsx")` or something. Thanks! I'm learning a lot here. :)

Comment: You already have connected to the workbook using `With wb.Application.Workbooks(sFileName)` Now you can connect to what ever sheet you want in that :)

Comment: Okay, I'm just not sure of the exact commands or syntax, but I'll play around and see what I come up with. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't that difficult after all. Instead of using the `With` construct I linked oXLApp to the required instance using the object pointer `wb` assigned during the call to `AccessibleObjectFromWindow`. This was done with `Set oXLApp = wb.Application` like in ForEachLoop's answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971473/can-vba-reach-across-instances-of-excel) thread. Once again, thanks for all the help! I'm out of the murky stuff for now.

Comment: This seems to work with Office 2013 as well, which is always nice!

Answer (score 2):

To see if an Excel file is open or not, you can use this function.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Data.xlsx"
    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(sFile)

    If Ret = True Then
        MsgBox "File is Open"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is not Open"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file is open
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. That works neatly. There is still the problem of finding if the current user has it open, or if it's open by another user. I found this just now, but I have yet to test it: [Checking if a Workbook is Open in any Excel Instance](http://www.thecodenet.com/articles.php?id=1)

Comment: I actually answered in your other post but deleted it :) I will get that post here :)

Comment: Posted it as a separate answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following only requires the workbook filename, not the full path:

```
Sub IsOpen()
 With CreateObject("Word.Application")
    If .Tasks.exists("Workbook.xlsb") Then MsgBox "The Workbook is open"
    .Quit
 End With
End Sub
```

This will succeed even if the workbook is open in a different instance of Excel.

(Yes, you use a `Word.Application` object even though you're interested in Excel....)

If you want to check a file by fully-qualified path use the function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22309698/2662901).

Answer (score -1):

you can check if file is open or not and get object if it is open

```
Public Shared Function isFileAlreadyOpen(ByVal xlFileName As String) As Boolean
    Return CBool(Not getIfBookOpened(xlFileName) Is Nothing)
End Function

Public Shared Function getIfBookOpened(ByVal xlFileName As String) As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wbBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlProcs() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    If xlProcs.Count > 0 Then
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        For Each wbBook In xlApp.Workbooks
            If wbBook.FullName.ToUpper = xlFileName.ToUpper Then
                Return wbBook
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

or

```
Public Shared Function getOrOpenBook(ByVal xlFileName As String) As Excel.Workbook
    Return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(xlFileName)
End Function
```